# Invalidate [invalidate]?

Tags: discussion, meta-tags

I stumbled over the [invalidate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/invalidate) tag and checked it out as I was curious about what it was supposed to be used for. Well, the tag wiki is empty: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/invalidate/info

- 380 questions, none of them with this tag alone (I scanned all 8
  pages)
- The vast majority of users only have 1 Q and/or A on it
- the related tags spread across many areas

Is this tag a good fit for meta-tag classification?

Comment: As far as I can tell this tag is completely superflous on every question tagged with it

Comment: It is a GUI primitive primarily.  With added patois from non-native English speakers.  It is quite harmless, reactivating hundreds of crappy questions just to get rid of it is not.

Comment: @HansPassant: then also an opportunity of getting rid of some crappy questions as well :)

Comment: It **might** refer to [`java.awt.Component#invalidate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#invalidate--) in some cases, but I didn't scan the usage list yet

Comment: Could this be about [invalidating the client area](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145005(v=vs.85).aspx) (for repainting) in Windows applications? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325894/difference-between-invalidaterect-and-redrawwindow) question is tagged _redraw_, which is probably just as appropriate and has less potential for misuse.

Comment: @Marco13 most common tag is android (158) followed by c# (46)

Answer (score 25):

I believe this is a meta tag. From all the questions I've viewed tagged with it, not one would be able to just be tagged with [invalidate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/invalidate).

It is:

- Ambiguous, as you can invalidate many things, in many languages, and in many processes, and not nearly all of these are even cursorily related
- Not descriptive. You can't tag a programming question with just [invalidate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/invalidate)
- Superflous. In all questions I've reviewed it provides no additional crucial information about the question

In consequence, I propose we burninate this tag.

Comment: We should not burninate specific technical terms just because some random people on meta have never heard of the term.

Comment: @Lundin Its consensus that tags classifiable as meta tags according to the specifications given in the canonical meta post on the matter should be burninated. The debate isn't about the merits at this point, just wether or not the tag is a meta-tag or not.

Comment: While the tag makes no sense to stand by itself, it makes perfect sense together with other tags. "winapi" + "invalidate" tags for example. If someone would be bothered to actually read the tag wiki before using the tag, or before proposing a burninate request, it would be obvious that this is not a meta tag.

Comment: @Lundin According to the (canonical burnination rules #1)[http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191] any tag that can not stand on its own is to be burninated off SO.

Comment: That means that 99% of all tags on SO should get removed then. Meta fundamentalism, here we go! You have to remove all tags like "subroutine", "function", "statement", "array", "pointer", "reference", "casting", "stack", "heap". And so on and so on.

Comment: @Lundin I don't make the rules, but they are official. Also all the tags you listed are effectively truly useless, so they should get removed, although there are probably too many questions in them to do it effectively without moderator intervention.

Comment: And what does the "official rules" say? "Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?" Yes. "and is it unambiguous?" No. "Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?" Yes. "Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?" Yes. "Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?" No. That made it all perfectly clear, didn't it? Now we know what to do!

Comment: @Lundin If you answered no to any of the above, the tag is to be burninated. (You did)

Comment: @Lundin again I didn't make these rules, and its not me you need to convince to change them.

Comment: @Lundin - To be fair, the wiki was only created yesterday. But I agree that this tag should not be burninated.

Comment: @JDB: I corrected the wiki. If someone wants a tag restricted to invalidating parts of a GUI, they should not simply take over a broader tag.

Comment: @Deduplicator - I'm not going to get in a war over this, but couldn't the same be said for someone who wants to take over a narrow tag to make it broader? In this case, the tag had no wiki, so I don't think it's true to say anyone "took it over".

Comment: @JDB: No wiki does not mean the tag has no meaning. If someone writes a tag-wiki, they should not just invent a scope for the tag, but work off current usage and what the tag could sensibly mean. Restricting it to just the usage for invalidating part of a GUI would be surprising.

Answer (score 3):

Invalidate is a technical term in the context of graphics programming. The tag wiki explains it quite well:

> Programmatically redraw some UI parts
>
> Invalidation is the process of forcibly redraw a UI. It is often
>   needed to update the appearance of one or more UI components after
>   some changes. It basically reloads and consequentially redraws the
>   specified UI component(s), or even the whole UI.

Most notably, this technical term is used plenty for Windows API GUI programming, which has functions such as `InvalidateRect`, that redraws a certain area of a window.

There is apparently a chance that the tag usage is misunderstood, because the technical term gets mixed up with the English words "invalid" and "invalidate".

I suggest that the tag should be renamed to [invalidate-graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/invalidate-graphics), [invalidate-redraw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/invalidate-redraw)  or similar.

Comment: Well, that's *one* of the definitions. And the one most relevant for GUI-programming, as there might not be anything else cached. Actually, the proper definition is far broader: "Invalidation is a way to mark some state as needing recalculation."

Comment: @Deduplicator If there are multiple definitions the tag must obviously be renamed, as proposed here.

Comment: Among the top 10 or so that I looked at, many of them dealt specifically with the graphics definition of "invalidate"/"invalidation".